# How to map parent column in EF 4.1 code first

Tags: entity-framework, poco, mapping-model

In my project I have following DomainModel.

```
public class Login
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public Login CreatedBy {get; set; }
}
```

I am using fluent configuration as below:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Login>()
            .HasKey(x => x.Id)
            .ToTable("Login");

modelBuilder.Entity<Login>()
            .HasOptional(x => x.CreatedBy)
            .WithMany()
            .HasForeignKey(x => x.CreatedBy);
```

My code in repository to get all Logins data is as below:

```
return from d in Db.Logins.Include("CreatedBy") 
       select d;
```

When I execute the code I am getting following error:

**The foreign key component 'CreatedBy' is not a declared property on type 'Login'. Verify that it has not been explicitly excluded from the model and that it is a valid primitive property.**

Can anyone suggest what I am doing wrong here?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> .. has not been explicitly excluded from the model and that **it is a
>   valid primitive property**

Your foreign key mapping `.HasForeignKey(x => x.CreatedBy)` does not use a primitive property.

```
public class Login
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public virtual Login CreatedBy {get; set; }
}
```

Then map it like

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Login>()
            .HasKey(x => x.Id)
            .ToTable("Login");

modelBuilder.Entity<Login>()
            .HasOptional(x => x.CreatedBy)
            .WithMany()
            .Map(x => x.MapKey("ForeignKeyColumn"));
```

Comment: Thanks for you reply. Actually I don't want to change my domain model.
Because I think my DomainModel is correct. I don't like to change my domain model for ORM. Just wondering how can I tell my ORM to load CreatedBy as Login object?

Comment: @learner edited answer. use `Map(x => x.MapKey("ForeignKeyColumn"))` to configure the FK column

Comment: Getting same error. The foreign key component 'CreatedBy' is not a declared property on type 'Login'. Verify that it has not been explicitly excluded from the model and that it is a valid primitive property.