# Autoincrement Int Id not inserted on related items

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework-core, asp.net-core-5.0, ef-core-5.0

Normally I use Guid's as Id's, but in this project I have to use int Id's, so my experience here is a little sparse.

My problem is that my autoincremental int Id's don't get a value OnAdd, that I can use on related items before I save changes.

Example:

```
var box = new Box
{
   Name = "Some name"
}
_dbContext.Add(box);

var boxItem = new BoxItem
{
    BoxId = box.Id, // This will be 0 on save
    Name = "Some other name"
}
_dbContext.Add(boxItem);

await _dbContext.SaveChangesAsync();
```

When I look in my database after the save, the boxItem.BoxId is 0.
When working with Guid's that would've got the Box.Id generated value.

The models:

```
public class Box
{

    [Key]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public IList<BoxItem> BoxItems { get; set; }

}

public class BoxItem
{

    [Key]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int BoxId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

}
```

The Id-column has "Identity specification" / "Is identity" = yes and "Identity increment" = 1 in the MSSQL-database.

I don't know if this is a limitation when working with int Id's, or my setup is incorrect?

Comment: `_dbContext.Add(box);` does not write the data to the database and generate the ID. `dbContext.SaveChangesAsync();` will write the data and generate value for autoincrement ID.

Comment: @ChetanRanpariya so I have to call SaveChanges after _dbContext.Add(box) and again after _dbContext.Add(boxItem) ? I know my setup would work with Guid's, but is that different with int Id's?

Comment: You can either call `SaveChanges` twice or map the entities correctly in EF. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6922690/how-to-map-child-entity-to-parent-entity-without-introducing-primitive-type-pare

Comment: @ChetanRanpariya I would like not to call SaveChanges twice. But I don't see how my convention based entities are not mapped correctly?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this is the right approach, but I solved it using this way:

```
var box = new Box
{
   Name = "Some name"
}
box.BoxItems = new List<BoxItem>(); // Line added

var boxItem = new BoxItem
{
    BoxId = box.Id,
    Name = "Some other name"
}
box.BoxItems.Add(boxItem);

_dbContext.Add(box); // Adding the box here with box.BoxItems instead

await _dbContext.SaveChangesAsync();
```